# Is there a simple way to condense if statements into a function to check arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord.js

I have a `switch` statement for handling commands, and it works as intended. However, I also have tons of commands/cases. The error checking is to make sure that the program won't crash if they type something that isn't a number. Is there a way to condense those `if statements` into a `function` somehow?

```
case "test":
        if (typeof args[1] === 'string') 
        {
            args[1] = parseInt(args[1])
            Functions.packs = args[1];
        }
        else if(Number.isNaN(+args[1]))
        {
            message.reply("The command was invalid.");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            message.reply("The command was invalid.");
            break;
        }
```

This is currently what the start of every command looks like, and it is becoming tedious to check commands. I have tried making a function for it, but nothing I tried has worked, so I doubt I'm on the right track.

Comment: What is `Functions.packs` ?

Comment: A variable inside another file called `Functions`. The variable needs to be set to what the user types in as the second argument (!test 2 means that packs = 2) etc.

Comment: Just check if he put a number, otherwise (else) display the error message

Comment: You can do this using regular expressions, for example: if(/[^\d]+/.test(args[1]) { // If you found a character other than a number ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attempt to use .toString() to force everything to be string and then parseInt() the result.  Allows you to just test for NaN...

```
var numberTest = function(testArg){
  var testString = testArg.toString();
  var testNumber = parseInt(testString);
  var returnObj = {
    number: testNumber,
    valid: Number.isNaN(testNumber)
  };
  return returnObj;
}

case "test":
  var argTest = numberTest(args[1]);
  if(argTest.valid){
    Functions.packs = argTest.number;
  }
  else{
    message.reply("The command was invalid.");
  }
  break;
```